# Is it really possible to plot excel vba graph for every nth row

Tags: vba, excel, plot

So I have an excel file which have 8000+ rows, and I have to plot a xlscatter graph based on the B2 to B8000 and C2 to C8000. but the values taken to plot the graph must use every 50th cell, I have found similar question [How to Use Every nth Cell in a Chart in Excel Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21459820/how-to-use-every-nth-cell-in-a-chart-in-excel-programmatically). but the code given do not plot graph, its just a blank graph. Is there any solution for this?

[...]

```
Dim xS As String

Dim yS As String

xS = "="

yS = "="

For i = 1 To 23000 step 50

    If i > 1 Then

        xS = xS & ","

        yS = yS & ","

    End If

    xS = xS & "A!$A$" & CStr(i)

    yS = yS & "A!$B$" & CStr(i)

Next

ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = xS

ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = yS
```

[...]

the one that I tried

Comment: It's SeriesCollection, not FullSeriesCollection. Aslo, make sure the chart has a series (even if empty) to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

First of all is the data coming from Sheet called A? if not then your code needs changing from:

```
xS = xS & "A!$A$" & CStr(i)
yS = yS & "A!$B$" & CStr(i)
```

To:

```
xS = xS & "Sheet1!$A$" & CStr(i) 'Where Sheet1 is your Sheet name.
yS = yS & "Sheet1!$B$" & CStr(i)
```

Also I'm pretty sure you should remove the following lines:

```
xS = "="
yS = "="
```

Comment: So I have done the changes on the code, but I am not sure how to show here, but it pops run time error"1004",application-defined or object-defined error on ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = xS , so I am wondering is it really possible to having the data source like this? Like all the other project all are Range("B1:B800") while this one is B1 , B4 , B6 ...